# The children's conversation: How many marbles do they have?

Tags: mathematics

**Tim:** "Wow, marbles! Lets share!"

**Ava:** "Yeah! We found them together, we should share equally. One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... There! We're equal!"

**Tim:** "No, I saw them first, I'll have two more than you! I'll take this, and this!"

**Ava:** "That's not fair!"

**Jack:** "Hey! What are you two doing with my marbles?"

**Tim:** "*Your* marbles?"

**Jack:** "Yeah, I put them there!"

**Tim:** "Sorry, I already dumped my *fair share* of marbles into my marble sack, and now I don't know how many are yours."

**Ava:** "Yeah, sorry, I dumped my unfair share of marbles into my marble sack too."

**Jack:** "Awww... Wait, I have an idea! You and Tim can simply give me half of the number of marbles in your bags, that should be fair."

**Tim:** "Okay."

**Ava:** "Fine."

**Tim:** "One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... There!"

**Ava:** "One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... Here's one left over!"

**Tim:** "I'll take that. In my pile it goes!"

**Ava:** "Hey! Why your pile?"

**Tim:** "Because it's an extra, right? Nobody's losing anything."

**Jack:** "Ummm... this is way less than I remembered to have!"

**Ava:** "Sorry, that's the best we can do for you, right Tim?"

**Tim:** "Yeah, take it or leave it."

**Jack:** "This is crazy! Return my marbles!"

**Ava:** "Hey! Get your hands off my marbles!"

**Tim:** "Hey! Mine too!"

**Jack:** "Too late, I dumped the marbles into my marble sack, bye!"

---

Ah... a typical kindergarten conversation, and everything seems well. But wait... is it fate or what that the crazy marble transactions all worked out?

**Tim, Ava and Jack now have the same number of marbles they started with!**

Given that when Jack forcefully grabbed from Tim's and Ava's pile, he grabbed 12 marbles more from Tim's pile then the amount he grabbed from Ava's pile:

> What is the minimum number of marbles each child needs to start with in order for this conversation to be able to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL; DR: the solution is

> Tim starts with $0$ marbles, Ava starts with $17$ marbles, and Jack starts with $44$ marbles.

#### Explanation:

Let $t$, $a$, and $j$ be the initial number of marbles that Tim, Ava, and Jack have, respectively. Let's go through the story and write it in mathematical language.

> **Tim:** "Wow, marbles! Lets share!"
>
> **Ava:** "Yeah! We found them together, we should share equally. One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... There! We're equal!"

> Now, Tim has $t+j/2$, Ava has $a+j/2$, and Jack has $0$.

This gives us the **first condition**:

> As no marbles are left, $j$ **is even**

> **Tim:** "No, I saw them first, I'll have two more than you! I'll take this, and this!"

> There is a problem here. If Tim takes two marbles from Ava, then Tim won't have two "new" marbles more than Ava, but 4. I assume that Tim does not know this, and that he indeed takes two marbles from Ava's pile.

> Now, Tim has $t+j/2+2$, Ava has $t+j/2-2$, and Jack has $0$

This gives us the **second condition**:

> $t+j/2\ge 2$

> **Ava:** "That's not fair!"
>
> **Jack:** "Hey! What are you two doing with my marbles?"
>
> **Tim:** "Your marbles?"
>
> **Jack:** "Yeah, I put them there!"
>
> **Tim:** "Sorry, I already dumped my fair share of marbles into my marble sack, and now I don't know how many are yours."
>
> **Ava:** "Yeah, sorry, I dumped my unfair share of marbles into my marble sack too."
>
> **Jack:** "Awww... Wait, I have an idea! You and Tim can simply give me half of the number of marbles in your bags, that should be fair."
>
> **Tim:** "Okay."
>
> **Ava:** "Fine."
>
> **Tim:** "One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... There!"

> Now, Tim has $t/2+j/4+1$, Ava has $a+j/2-2$, and Jack has $t/2+j/4+1$.

This gives us our **third condition**:

> No leftover marbles, so $t+j/2+2$ is even, or, equivalently, $t+j/2$ **is even**.

> **Ava:** "One for your pile, one for my pile, another for your pile, another... Here's one left over!"
>
> **Tim:** "I'll take that. In my pile it goes!"

> Now, Tim has $t/2+j/4+2$, Ava has $(a-1)/2+j/4-1$, and Jack has $t/2+(a-1)/2+j/2$.

This gives us our **fourth condition**:

> $a+j/2-2$ is odd, or, equivalently, $a+j/2$ **is odd.**

> **Ava:** "Hey! Why your pile?"
>
> **Tim:** "Because it's an extra, right? Nobody's losing anything."
>
> **Jack:** "Ummm... this is way less than I remembered to have!"

This gives us our **fifth condition**:

> $t/2+(a-1)/2+j/2\ll j$. **Equivalently**, $t+a-1\ll j$.

> **Ava:** "Sorry, that's the best we can do for you, right Tim?"
>
> **Tim:** "Yeah, take it or leave it."
>
> **Jack:** "This is crazy! Return my marbles!"
>
> **Ava:** "Hey! Get your hands off my marbles!"
>
> **Tim:** "Hey! Mine too!"
>
> **Jack:** "Too late, I dumped the marbles into my marble sack, bye!"

Now, they all have the same number of marbles as they had at the beginning. This means that Jack took from Tim

> $t-[t/2+j/4+2]=j/4+2-t/2$ **marbles**

and Jack took from Ava

> $a-[(a-1)/2+j/4-1]=j/4-2-(a-1)/2$ **marbles**

Jack took from Tim 12 more than from Ava, which gives us our **sixth condition**:

> $$\frac{j}{4}+2-\frac{t}{2}=12+\frac{j}{4}-2-\frac{a-1}{2}$$
>  or equivalently
> $$a-t=17$$

and our **seventh condition**:

> Jack must take at least one marble from Ava, so
>  $$\frac{j}{4}-2-\frac{a-1}{2}\ge 1$$
>  or equivalently
>  $$j\ge 2a+10$$

Now it is time to find the minimal $t$, $a$, and $j$ that satisfy all seven conditions:

> - None of the conditions has $t$ on the large side of an inequality, so **we set** $t=0$ and see where that takes us.
>  
>  - From the **sixth condition**, we have $a=17$.
>  
>  - From the **seventh condition**, we have $j\ge 44$. **We set** $j=40$ and see what happens.
>  
>  - **First condition:** $j$ is even: check.
>  
>  - **Second condition:** $t+j/2\ge 2$. We have $t+j/2=22$, so check.
>  
>  - **Third condition:** $t+j/2$ is even: check.
>  
>  - **Fourth condition:** $a+j/2$ is odd. We have $a+j/2=39$, so check.
>  
>  - **Fifth condition:** $t+a-1\ll j$ We have $16\ll 44$, so check.

All conditions are satisfied, so the solution is

> $t=0$, $a=17$, $j=44$.

If you follow the story again, everything adds up. In the last step,

> Jack takes $13$ from Tim, and Jack takes $1$ from Ava, going from (Tim:13, Ava:18, Jack:30) to the final stage (Tim:0, Ava:17, Jack:44), which is equal to the initial stage.